# Attempt to Display Local PDF With WKWebView Results in White Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, wkwebview

I have a PDF file stored in my local applications directory. I wrote the following code years ago to display the pdf in a webView. It has worked flawlessly, but no longer works. It instead displays a white screen.

```
NSString* pdfFileName = [self getPDFFileName];

WKWebView* webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfFileName];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I have since tried other methods of WKWebView such as:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" characterEncodingName:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfFileName]];
```

or

```
[webView loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:url];
```

but these don't work either.

What changed that is preventing a local pdf from displaying?

Comment: Change `[NSURL URLWithString:pdfFileName];` to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFileName];`. This assumes that `pdfFileName` is actually a full file path and not just a filename.

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks for the suggestion. My pdfFileName is "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DD7F8898-9184-4341-BE3E-4CF8649C94DD/Documents/Flower Box Cutting Instructions.pdf". I have tried your suggestion before. It gives the same result, but also gives an error in the console "[Process] 0x138830e18 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=31922] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, isMainFrame=1, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-1100, isMainFrame=1", which is understandable since my file name is the absolute location

Comment: Based on the comment of @HangarRash, I determined that the file itself was corrupt. HangarRash solution is the correct once you have a valid file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:
`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:<valid_file_path>]`

Always use your file browser to confirm both the file path and the path itself are valid in case of any issues.